# Creating JDialog in actionperformed

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, modal-dialog, jdialog

I'm working on a swing application for reading a JSON file and then writing the same to a file. Action items will be listed in a JTable row that shows the metadata of the file and the last column of each row has a button for printing the JSON into a local file.

In the action performed, I'm planning to show a custom JDialog to prevent any operations in the UI, this is blocking all further steps, like writing the file.

Is this possible to start a thread to invoke a function for file reoperations after showing the JDialog? I tried this way using Thread, but this also got blocked.

```
@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton printerButton = (JButton) e.getSource();
        String ac = printerButton.getActionCommand();
        System.out.println("ac = " + ac);
        
        /*
         * **Start JDialog for blocking any operation on the window** 
         */
        
        /*
         * **Start a thread for writing a file**
         */
    }
```

Comment: So, are you trying to do operations in the background? Use a Swing Worker for this particular case

Comment: The code placed AFTER the dialog.setVisible(true) does not execute until the "modal" dialog is closed. So you need to start the Thread (or SwingWorker) BEFORE you make the dialog visible. The SwingWorker is easiest to use because your will know when the task is finished and you just add logic in the `done()` method of the SwingWorker to close the dialog. Read the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information and examples.